# Design Database schema for billing system

Tags: database-schema, normalization

I want to design a database for billing system. In one bill a customer might have purchased multiple different items ,for example fot bill Id 1 customer purchased 2 apples  3 bananas and 1 watermelon. i want to know how i can normalize this database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty standard, basic normalization exercise with a pretty standard solution. The usual approach is to have an `orders` table containing order ID, customer ID, order date &c., and an `order_items` table with a record for each line item on the order.

Comment: in order_items for same order id i will have multiple rows right ??

Comment: That's correct. Typically you index line_items on order_id, item_num.